# XCode project - macro for unique server addresses for each developer

Tags: xcode, macros, preprocessor

As I develop an iPhone app that speaks to a Rails app running on my laptop, I'll do something like,

```
    model.serverIp = @"192.168.0.23";
```

I'll commit this, and the next guy checks it out, and changes it to his IP address, and then commits, and then I have to change it........

What's the best way to avoid stepping on each other's toes here?

Answer (score 1):

For development purposes it may suffice to one of several things:

- Specify an external file that is not checked in which contains the relevant IP address and is added as a resource file to the iPhone app
- Add code to the application so it can discern the IP address automatically
- Use a loopback address (assuming the test server is always running on the same machine as the iPhone app)
- Deploy a common server with a fixed IP address for everyone to use